# Strange issue when installing .apk file in samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, apk

I have a strange issue.

I have my .apk file in my mac machine and i sent that file to my Galaxy Tab via bluetooth. when i installed that file,  that app gets installed but i get many instance of the same app...

Also when i unintsall the app, all the app instances gets deleted

As i am a newb in android development, please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks for any help

This is my manifest file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/co_logo" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.Loading"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.CoDb"  
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"                
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>            
    <activity android:name=".Login"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.OrderPrompt"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>            
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.New_Order_Screen_1"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.New_Order_Screen_2"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.Enrich_Order"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.Customer_Feedback"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>   
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.Prompt"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>   
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.Enrich_Order"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.Enrich_Order_List"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.PopupMenu"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.co.sampling.Order_NewOrder_2"   
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"               
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>             
</application>
```

Comment: when i tap on the file, it asks me like want to install? i press yes ...this wat i done

Comment: Yes when uninstalling all the instances get deleted

Comment: Yeah. also post it here. Pls edit your question adding it to the question. Dont paste it in comments.

Comment: In that manifest file what i should check for please?

Comment: post it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

should be present only in the main activity tag. Remove from all other activity tags. 

 
Adding this intent filter indicates that this activity is the main activity of the app and should be listed in the launcher(apps drawer)

Answer (score 0):

And I would add that the android:label should only be present on the application tag, not anywhere else.